# Google Maps widget in Flutter, how to move or remove zoom button

Tags: flutter, widget, maps

So basically I was wondering if there's any way to move the position of this button, or even remove it.

[image]

I need to move/remove it because when using `extendBody: true` in order to show the map even behind of the FBA, the button stays in the middle of the BottomNavBar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the visibility of the zoom control buttons by setting the `zoomControlsEnabled` property ([docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/zoomControlsEnabled.html)) when displaying the Google Maps widget:

```dart
GoogleMap(
  ...
  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
  ...
)
```

Comment: No problem! Take into account that the docs state that this setting is ignored in iOS (maybe because it's already hidden?).